# Undeclared identifier in class implementation file

Tags: c++, class, implementation

Plorg.h:

```
#include <string>
    #ifndef PLORG_H
    #define PLORG_H

class Plorg{
private:
    string name;
    int CI;

public:
    Plorg();
    Plorg(const string & n,int x=50);
    ~Plorg();
    void ChangeID(int CIaux);
    void Report() const;
};  
#endif PLORG_H
```

Plorg.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Plorg.h"

using namespace std;
Plorg::Plorg(){
    name="Plorga";
    CI=50;
};

Plorg::Plorg(const string & n,int CIaux=50){
    name=n;
    CI=CIaux;
};
void Plorg::ChangeID(int CIaux){
    CI=CIaux;
};

void Plorg::Report() const {
    cout << "My name is " << name << "!" <<endl;
    cout << "MY CI is" << CI << "." ;
};

Plorg::~Plorg(){
    cout << "Bye,human" ;
};
```

I get this error,thoguh:

Error   11  error C2065: 'name' : undeclared identifier c:\users\work\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\book\firstclass\firstclass\plorg.cpp    7   1   firstclass

So,what should I do?

Comment: You should be using a constructor initializer list. I don't think that's your first error, either.

Comment: Your members in "Plorg.h" are all missing their `std::` namespace qualifiers. Do NOT put `using namespace std;` in you header. Fix the member and constructor parameter variable declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is really `std::string`:

```
class Plorg{
private:
    std::string name;
//  ^^^
public:
    Plorg();
    Plorg(const std::string& n, int x=50);
//              ^^^
```

As an aside, you should favour the constructor initialization list, and don't put the default parameter value in the implementation:

```
Plorg::Plorg(const std::string & n, int CIaux) : name(n), CI(CIAux) {}
```

Comment: Thanks,I still find it amazing that people like you find time to answer questions to people like me. You're golden.